# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ycor'

Tags: python, python-turtle, pong

I trying to make a pong game using turtle library and I got this error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ycor'.

This is my code:

```
#red, green, blue
import turtle

#Functions
def sprite(animation_speed, shape, color, x, y, size_width, size_height):
 sprite = turtle.Turtle()
 sprite.penup()
 sprite.speed(animation_speed)
 sprite.shape(shape)
 sprite.color(color)
 sprite.goto(x,y)
 sprite.shapesize(stretch_wid = size_height, stretch_len = size_width)

def paddle1Up():
 y = paddle1.ycor()
 y += 5
 paddle1.sety(y)

#Window settings
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Pong game")
window.bgcolor("#0096ff")
window.setup(width = 1920, height = 1080)
window.tracer(0)

#Start
paddle1 = sprite(0, "square", "purple", -800, 0, 3, 12)
paddle2 = sprite(0, "square", "purple", 800, 0, 3, 12)
ball = sprite(0, "circle", "white", 0, 0, 3, 3)

#keyboard biding
window.listen()
window.onkeypress(paddle1Up(), "w")

#Main game loop
while True:
 window.update()
```

The error is in this line: 'window.onkeypress(paddle1Up(), "w")'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and preferably indent it with the usual four spaces (see PEP-8, IIRC). As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two critical errors in this code.  First is that three variables are assigned to the result of a `sprite()` call:

```
paddle1 = sprite(0, "square", "purple", -800, 0, 3, 12)
paddle2 = sprite(0, "square", "purple", 800, 0, 3, 12)
ball = sprite(0, "circle", "white", 0, 0, 3, 3)
```

But the `sprite()` function doesn't return *anything* except `None`.  The next problem is this call is incorrect:

```
window.onkeypress(paddle1Up(), "w")
```

We should be passing the function `paddle1Up` to `onkeypress()`, not the result of calling the function `paddle1Up()`.  A less severe issue is that you have a variable and a function both called `sprite`.  A dangerous practice, avoid it.  Addressing all three issues above, we get the code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Functions
def create_sprite(animation_speed, shape, color, x, y, size_width, size_height):
    sprite = Turtle()
    sprite.shape(shape)
    sprite.shapesize(stretch_wid=size_height, stretch_len=size_width)
    sprite.speed(animation_speed)
    sprite.color(color)
    sprite.penup()
    sprite.goto(x, y)

    return sprite

def paddle1Up():
    paddle1.sety(paddle1.ycor() + 5)

# Screen settings
screen = Screen()
screen.title("Pong game")
screen.bgcolor('#0096ff')
screen.setup(width=1920, height=1080)
screen.tracer(0)

paddle1 = create_sprite(0, 'square', 'purple', -800, 0, 3, 12)
paddle2 = create_sprite(0, 'square', 'purple', 800, 0, 3, 12)
ball = create_sprite(0, 'circle', 'white', 0, 0, 3, 3)

# keyboard binding
screen.onkeypress(paddle1Up, 'w')
screen.listen()

# Main game loop
while True:
    screen.update()
```

Which basically does what you set out to do but still has one issue that might become a problem as you expand on this code.